# Solr query not working when used with OR Crotch

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr

Am currently trying to make as query using the class provided by solr "Query" and SimpleFilterQuery, with my need am required to make a double query whereas only one of the query needs to match, each query work independently without the other, but when i add the or query its stopped working, my guess will be or is working like AND

```
.addFilterQuery(new SimpleFilterQuery()
                            .addCriteria(Criteria.where("registeration_date")
                                                 .greaterThanEqual(new Date())
                                                 .or("registeration_date").isNull()))
```

Any solution or workaround to this will be appreciated

Comment: Check the log on the Solr side to see what query was actually generated - could it be that the `or` part requires an explicit Criteria class itself?

Comment: @MatsLindh base on my debug the query looks like this AND ( ! registeration_date$between:[Ljava.lang.Object;@4947a0d6 OR registeration_date$between:[Ljava.lang.Object;@1d7b8667 ) while [Ljava.lang.Object;@4947a0d6 is the current date and [Ljava.lang.Object;@1d7b8667 is null in the memory

Comment: If that's what Solr sees on its side, I have no idea how that would work for Solr, since the objects have been serialized directly instead of building a query. Or are you debugging this inside your Java application?

Comment: Yes, am debugging inside my application, actually the FilterQuery work with is "isnull" without adding the "or" and also "greatherthanequal" also work without the "or", i can't find the solr log, still taking a look

Comment: You'll have a `Logging` tab under the Admin interface where all log messages can be seen. Be sure to change the log level to INFO to see the queries logged. My guess is that the `or` maps to the wrong level of your query.